# Apple Pay Payment not going through even though clientSecret was retrieved

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay, passkit

The goal is to just make a successful Apple Pay payment and be done with this API integration.
I'm literally on the brink of success but I have just one more bug I can't figure out.

```
func startApplePayCheckout() {
    let backendUrlForIntent = "https://us-central1-xxxxx-41f12.cloudfunctions.net/createPaymentIntent"
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
    getUsersStripeCustomerID { (customerid) in
        if let id = customerid {
            // Create a PaymentIntent as soon as the view loads
            let costAsAnInt = self.actualCostOfEvent.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
            let costForStripe = Int(costAsAnInt!)
            let url = URL(string: backendUrlForIntent)!
            let json: [String: Any] = [
                "amount": costForStripe! + (self.gothereFee * Int(self.stepperValue.value)),
                "currency": "CAD",
                "customer": id,
                "setup_future_usage": "on_session",
            ]
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      response.statusCode == 200,
                      let data = data,
                      let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                      let clientSecret = json["clientSecret"] as? String else {
                    let message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to decode response from server."
                    self?.displayCancelledAlert(title: "Error Loading Page", message: message)
                    return
                }
                guard let paymentIntentID = json["paymentIntentID"] as? String else { return }
                
                self?.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(self?.nameToUseInAPICall)").setData(["stripePaymentIntentID": paymentIntentID], merge: true, completion: { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("There was an error setting the paymentIntentID in the document: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("PaymentIntentID successfully stored!")
                    }
                })
                print("Created PaymentIntent")
                self?.paymentIntentClientSecret = clientSecret
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

I call this right when the Apple Pay sheet is presented. The print statements work fine, the clientSecret gets retrieved. Now when I actually try to pay, I still get a "Payment Not Completed", this is what I have in the `didCreatePaymentMethod` function:

```
func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
    guard let paymentIntentClient = paymentIntentClientSecret else {
        print("There is an issue with the clientSecret")
        return
    }
    
    let error = NSError(domain: backendUrl, code: 400, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "The payment cannot go through for some reason!"])
    
    let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: paymentIntentClient)
    paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodId = paymentMethod.stripeId
    
    let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
    paymentHandler.confirmPayment(paymentIntentParams, with: self) { (status, intent, error) in
        switch status {
        case .canceled:
            print("Payment Canceled")
            break
        case .failed:
            print("Payment Failed")
            break
        case .succeeded:
            print("Payment Succeeded")
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    completion(paymentIntentClient, error)

}
```

**EDIT**
So with this implemented, the payment actually charges now when I check in the logs, but for the actual Apple Pay itself, it never shows the success message in the Apple Pay sheet. Here is what I have in the `didCompleteWithStatus` method:

```
 func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
    
    guard status == .success else {
        print("Payment couldn't go through")
        return
    }
}
```

So the weird thing that's going on is that, the first method ends up being successful and the charge is shown in the API Call logs, but the `didCompleteWith...` method always finishes with an error status and a "Payment Not Completed" on the Apple sheet and for the life of me I cannot understand why.

Comment: What is the status of the Payment Intent after you go through this process?  Are there any hints as to what's happening in the Stripe Dashboard under Developer > Logs and Developer > Events?

Comment: Hold on, let me edit the post, I added a couple things. @Justin Michael

Comment: just finished editing, take a look now @Justin Michael

Comment: In your `applePayContext:didCompleteWithStatus:error:` delegate method try logging both `status` and `error` and add the details to your message.

Comment: Oh, wait a second, I think I see the issue.  You're creating an actual `error` and feeding it to the `completion` handler.  If you remove the `let error = NSError...` line does it work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're creating an error on this line:

```swift
let error = NSError(domain: backendUrl, code: 400, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "The payment cannot go through for some reason!"])
```

And then feeding that error into the `completion` handler here:

```swift
completion(paymentIntentClient, error)
```

That results in the "Payment not complete" error being shown in the Apple Pay sheet.

The idea with the `completion` handler is to provide it a Payment Intent's client secret *or* an error if you can't provide it with a client secret, not both.  [The documentation](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPApplePayContextDelegate.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(pl)STPApplePayContextDelegate(im)applePayContext:didCreatePaymentMethod:paymentInformation:completion:) explains this:

> Call this with the PaymentIntent’s client secret, or the error that occurred creating the PaymentIntent.

If you call `completion` without the `error` you should be all set.

Comment: There has to be two parameters in the completion block. One string, that being the clientSecret, and one Error data type. @Justin Michael

Comment: Nvm just had to put nil, it works great now. Thanks for all the help in the last week or so, really appreciate it. @Justin Michael